# Handle SQL/PHP output and convert into java

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have no idea how i do this, i have some pieces of code, that i need to "handle" and use in javascript for some search engine

This is what i have in my database

```
[
["Reparation", "Pris"],
["Fejlfinding", "Gratis"],
["Udskiftning af Skærm (Refurbished)", "3699,-"]
]
```

This is what i need it to look like after i get it from the database and it has been handled.

```
var searchChoices = {


"Name": {

    "Model Name": {
        "icons": {
            "dark": "Imagelink",
            "light": "imagelink"
        },

        "items": [

        {
            "headline": "Gratis",
            "text": "Fejlfinding"
        }, 

        {
            "headline": "3699",
            "text": "Udskiftning af Skærm (Refurbished)"
        }

        ]

    }
}
};
```

I have really no idea how to do this? I don't even know what it's called.

Can someone please help me, or point me in the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use php [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to send data to javascript. You can make something like this:

```
<script>
var data = <?=json_encode($data);?>
...
```

Next step is simple loop to add items:

```
for(var row in data)
    searchChoices["Name"]["Model name"].items.push({
        "headline": data[row][1],
        "text": data[row][0]
    });
```

You can also generate whole javascript object using PHP:

```
<script>
var searchChoices = {
    "Name": {

    "Model Name": {
        "icons": {
            "dark": "Imagelink",
            "light": "imagelink"
        },

        "items": [
        <?php
            foreach($data as $row)
                echo '{"headline": "' . $row[1] . '", "text": "' . $row[0] . '"},';
        ?>
        ]
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: What i have in my database, is in a single colum, so i can not handle each row/colum. :3 and i don't understand everything you're saying :3

Comment: I see that you edited you're anwser, but it will not work, the data i have is in a single collum, as i posted above. not in diffents rows :)

Comment: OK, I think I understand. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3886356/9986020) your solution?

Comment: No unfurtunaly not, what i have is not php, java or something else, its raw data in the the form as postet, nothing else :3

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is another solution, regular expression:

```
(\[\"(.+)\"\,\ ?\"(.+)\"\]\,?)
```

The next step is to get data from `preg_match_all` result.

This is simple script i wrote to test:

```
<?php
$data = <<<JS
[
    ["Reparation", "Pris"],
    ["Fejlfinding", "Gratis"],
    ["Udskiftning af Skærm (Refurbished)", "3699,-"]
]
JS;

$pattern = '/(\[\"(.+)\"\,\ ?\"(.+)\"\]\,?)/';
$matches = [];

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);

for($i=0, $j=count($matches[2]); $i<$j; $i++) {
    echo '{"headline": "' . $matches[3][$i] . '", "text": "' . $matches[2][$i] . '"},' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey Arc :) the script is working, but I have some problems, are you up for helping me :)? if I take the data directly from the DB, (Hardcoded) as well, the output is broken, but if I run it through a javascript beautifier, it works fine. from the DB it break because all of the ] does not transform correctly... I think I may can be fixet by the pattern? but Regx is not my strong side :3

Comment: This is new pattern: `/(\"([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\ ÆØÅæøå]+)\"\,\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\,\-)?\")/`
This is not perfect, becaouse i added characters `(` and `)` to pattern, but you must be sure that there is no more special characters. Second, pattern have also characters like: `ÆØÅæøå`. Check this to as much records as possible, but remember that this could not be reliable to all situations (ex. string with character `\"`) :(